# Include header files in c++

Tags: c++, include

The C++ Premier I have doesn't say much about what I am about to ask, and this is what I got googling [LINK](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/):

*When the compiler compiles the #include "example.h" line, it copies the contents of example.h into the current file.*

So, if that's true, in the following example why B.h doesn't know about A.h ? Is it how the files are compiled ? Do I have to include A.h in every file that use it and then include every file that use A.h in the program.h that uses these files ?

```
In program.h
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
```

Comment: It does! But it is good practice to include a header directly whenever you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**WARNING: VERY BAD CODE:**

`a.h`

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#define SOME_LIT "string lit in A.h"

#endif
```

`b.h`

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include <iostream>

void foo() { std::cout << SOME_LIT << '\n'; }

#endif
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Prints:

```
$ ./a.out 
string lit in A.h
```

So you can see `b.h` knows about the `define` in `a.h`. If you forgot the `#include "a.h"`, or put it *below* `#include "b.h"`, this would break.

As a general rule however, you should explicitly `#include` a header in any file you need it. That way you know that you only care about `foo` in `main`, so you just `#include` the `foo` header, which is `b.h`:

```
#include "b.h"
int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Comment: That's strange, it didn't work for me, for a mvc project I am working, I have numerous subclasses in their separate files, and the base class in it's separate file, then in the controller class file, I am doing something like : #include "basefile.h" #include "child1.h" #include "child2.h" and so on.. but I get compile time errors stating that baseclass doesn't doesn't name a type in child1.h(or something similar)

Comment: Well, **b.h** only knows about the **define** in **a.h** in the context of **main.cpp** in your example. If only **b.h** is included, you'll get errors.

Comment: 2 possibilities: 1) You don't have your compilation configured correctly so it can't pick up one of the headers. 2) You have made a mistake in the order you include things. I think 2 is the more common problem. This is why it is recommended to always include everything you need in the file in which you use it.

Comment: @PureW Yes, that is exactly the question. Was that not clear? Also why I included the warning and the recommendation at the end.

Comment: @PureW "Well, b.h only knows about the define in a.h in the context of main.cpp in your example". That makes more sense. So if I need to know about A.h in B.h, then this won't work ? Is there any cleaner option where I don't have to include baseclass file in every subclass file ?

Comment: @PureW and does it mean the code is not executed from top to bottom, I mean when the declaration for example A myClass; in B.h is executed, why its not recognized, when the A.h was included just above it ?

Comment: @StudentX *In this case* `b.h` knows about `a.h`. If you then included `b.h` in a *different* translation unit (.cpp file) *and* forgot to include `a.h`, you would get errors. It should work the way you have written in the question, but it is *very* easy to get wrong. Instead, you should `#include "a.h"` at the top of `b.h`.

Comment: @StudentX You shouldn't think of h-files as being executed. They are simply pasted into your source-files using the `#include`. Only .c/.cpp-files are actually compiled. You should do what @BoBTFish said, if **b.h** really requires **a.h**, then **b.h** should include **a.h**

Comment: I don't know how to do it in msvc, but if you can use `g++` or `clang++`, use the `-E` command line option to just apply the preprocessing. Then you can see that `#include`s are literally just pasted in.